# How to find all integer solutions for underdetermined sytsem of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, linear-diophantine-equations

I do have a system of n equations with m variables where m > n with integer coefficients. I wish to find a set of integer solutions to this system (In my case n = 2 and m = 4). Could somebody tell me how I can do it? I already solved this system with Mathematica but I would like to redo these calculations by hand to understand how their were obtained.

The system is:
$\left\{
\begin{array}{l l}
4u - 3v + 4w + 3z = 1\\
-4v - 3u - 4z + 3w = 0
\end{array} \right.$

Comment: Yes, they are. I've updated my question.

Comment: Can you give us the $2$ equations in $4$ variables ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Here you go. In general, coefficients can change but in accordance with some rules. Therefore, if I will know technique how to solve this special instance I will know everything, I hope.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I made typo in equations, right now is fine.

Comment: The Maple command [isolve](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=isolve) produces 
$$  \left\{ u=-3-18\,{\it Z1}-25\,{\it Z2},v={\it Z1},w=1+6\,{\it 
Z1}+7\,{\it Z2},z=3+17\,{\it Z1}+24\,{\it Z2} \right\} $$ , where $Z1,Z2$ are arbitrary integers.

Answer (score 2):

A linear equation with integer coefficients, where one looks for integer solutions is called a linear Diophantine equation.

The simplest case
$$
a x + b y = c
$$
can be solved systematically and has either no or infinite many solutions.

From here one can move to more variables or more equations.

See [System of linear Diophantine equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#System_of_linear_Diophantine_equations) on how you might proceed. It recommends calculating the Smith normal form.

Answer (score 1):

Well, finally I have used old good Hermite Normal Form. I knew this method before but I thought about something which could be easier for bigger systems to solve by hand.

If something check paper [Linear Diophantine Equations, W. J. Gilbert, A. Pathria, 1990](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~wgilbert/Research/GilbertPathria.pdf).

What they used is just unimodular row operations to obtain HNF and matrix U at once. In my case I had to work on symbol coefficients and this approach led me to all what I needed. Well, if you know any better way I will be happy to give it a try. I know about Smith Normal Form but it sounds to complex - well, I have to say that I have never tried to us SNF. Maybe I should.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way, as I know, to determine all integer solutions to the system. You should at first find all real solutions to the system, this gives you a subspace $V\subset\mathbb R^m$ of dimension at least $m-n$. Now for finding all integer solutions you should find the lattice points of the subspace $V$.

Comment: Well in this particular it must be possible because this problem is related to the Bézout Identity.